# Cannot access a webservice via WP8 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a windows phone 8 application which access another webservice. On the response code like:

```
private void OnGetResponse<TRequest, TResponse>(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            var state = (AsyncRequestState<TRequest, TResponse>)result.AsyncState;
            try
            {
                using (var webResponse = state.WebRequest.EndGetResponse(result))
                {
                  using (var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                  {
                    var response = formatter.Deserialize<TResponse>(responseStream);
                    state.TaskCompletionSource.SetResult(response);
                    state.Complete();
                  }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {

            }
           }
        }
```

when code executes this line

```
using (var webResponse = state.WebRequest.EndGetResponse(result))
```

error throws out saying:
**System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound**

But I can access the webservice via the built in IE. This means that the enumelator can access the internet.
So what's the problem ? help please ~

Comment: Does your remote address contains "https://" ?

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware No, it's just "http://". confused about this.

Comment: Try to get a basic webpage or a simple rss feed from google.  If that works, it probably not your code but a setting on the remote server's end.  Or maybe you need to send specific http headers to the remote server as well.  It is hard to debug the problem with the information that you provided.

Comment: most probably your headers are missing from the request. Use fiddler or something to catch hold of the exact headers sent while testing from IE, then use the same headers and try.